# Comment box in a blog

Tags: templates, comments, blogs, blogger, box

I'm the writer of the blog www.lenukikuki.com
Some time ago I decided to disable the option of commenting on my blogposts. I can't remember what did I do, but now there's no comment box and there's no option for commenting.
Now I want the comment box back. It's not a problem of the html cause I've just deleted the whole pattern and redone it.
Plus, on blogger the > settings > comment location  is "full page" so it should be ok

Please is there anyone who can help me? I'm in trouble

Comment: Try the Embedded option instead of the "Full page" and see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

There is a new option in blogger for Comments.

You can enable Google+ comments by going to Settings -> Posts, comments and sharing.

Use Google+ Comments on this blog **select Yes**

Also check if you have allowed reader to comment on your posts or not by opening any post you have published and in the right hand side you will see the Options part there you have to allow comments.

Refer this image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRc75.png)